# Do I have any standing to receive back pay after a pay cut?

Tags: salary, legal

I started a job at a very small company (~10 employees) last year. The majority of the business is based on contracts with clients, primarily doing government related work. A few months ago it was announced that there were some cash flow issues and they were cutting everyone's pay to 50% until contract payments came in. It was also stated that there would be back pay for the wages when the payments were made. As of now pay is still at 50%.

How much legal standing do I have to get the back pay in the event I find a new job or get laid off?

The only documents I signed are the offer letter and initial employment contract (and related new hire documents, healthcare, benefits, etc.).

I like the people I work with and enjoy the work itself, so I'm hesitant to jump ship as long as I know I'm not significantly risking a large portion of my salary.

<sub>I am unsure if this should be here or on [the legal Stack Exchange site](https://law.stackexchange.com/tour). This seemed like the best place to start.</sub>

Comment: Hi there, welcome to TWP. Unfortunately, this post seems far crossing the line of being on/off-topic. "*How much legal standing do I have*": ask a union/lawyer first. "*I'm hesitant to jump ship*": ask yourself :) random strangers on the internet can't be really helpful when it comes to legal or personal choices.

Comment: Even on Law.SE your question is not answerable. You did not even give a juristiction. Where I live, even cutting your pay that way would have been completely illegal.

Answer (score 5):

I'm sorry to break it to you, but you're probably never going to see any of that "back pay". "Cash flow issues" is almost universally a lie and actually means "outgoings are more than income"; your employer will likely go bust in the next few months.

Start using the 50% of your time you're not being paid for to find a new job.

Comment: 50% Pay = 50% work.